# Probability Density Function Plots for random.random in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, random

I am a newbie to python, and I want to generate the identical PDF plots as shown below:

[image]

Here is my current version of implementation, which doesn't produce the same plots:

```py
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure('PDF for random.random()')
plt.title('PDF for random.random()')
plt.plot(random.random())

plt.figure('PDF for random.random() + random.random()')
plt.title('PDF for random.random() + random.random()')
plt.plot(random.random() + random.random())

plt.figure('PDF for random.random() + random.random() + random.random()')
plt.title('PDF for random.random() + random.random() + random.random()')
plt.plot(random.random() + random.random() + random.random())

plt.show()
```

Where did I do it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For speed purposes, you could use `numpy.random` which provides a [vectorized](https://unidata.github.io/python-training/workshop/NumPy/numpy-broadcasting-and-vectorization/) equivalent for `random.random`.

To get smoothened curves, a ['kde'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) can be plotted.  Such a kde curve represents each data point with a small gaussian curve, and adds them all up.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

N = 1_000_000

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(16, 4))

sns.kdeplot(np.random.rand(N), ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title("PDF for\nrandom.random()")

sns.kdeplot(np.random.rand(N) + np.random.rand(N), ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title("PDF for\nrandom.random()+random.random()")

sns.kdeplot(np.random.rand(N) + np.random.rand(N) + np.random.rand(N), ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title("PDF for\nrandom.random()+random.random()+random.random()")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: kde curves for sums of random numbers]

Answer (score 2):

Calling `random.random()` once simply returns a single number, you need to call it multiple times in order to get a good enough sample of the underlying distribution.

You can create a list with `n` calls to `random.random` by writing `[random.random() for _ in range(n)]`.

Try this code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample_size = 10000

fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3)

ax1.hist([random.random() for _ in range(sample_size)])
ax1.set_title('PDF for random.random()')

ax2.hist([random.random() + random.random() for _ in range(sample_size)])
ax2.set_title('PDF for random.random() + random.random()')

ax3.hist([random.random() + random.random() + random.random() for _ in range(sample_size)])
ax3.set_title('PDF for random.random() + random.random() + random.random()')

plt.show()
```

output image:

[image]

Comment: With `histtype='step'` and more bins (e.g. `bins=50`), the plots could be more similar to the original post.